# Send file return 405(method not allow)

Tags: javascript, php, http-status-code-405

Client send a file to Server. The request it's made with XMLHttpRequest(). I'm using PHP as server. When running in browser the upload from file  [return this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqX3i.png) 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED). 
The required header is already in PHP code. I do not understand why it does not work

PHP

```
<?php                                                         
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");                   
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');                  
  $fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : 
  false);

  if ($fn) {

    // AJAX call
    file_put_contents(
    'uploads/' . $fn,
    file_get_contents('php://input')
    );
    echo "$fn uploaded";
    exit();

  }
else {

// form submit
$files = $_FILES['fileselect'];

foreach ($files['error'] as $id => $err) {
    if ($err == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $fn = $files['name'][$id];
        move_uploaded_file(
            $files['tmp_name'][$id],
            'uploads/' . $fn
        );
        echo "<p>File $fn uploaded.</p>";
    }
   }
 }
```

JavaScript

```
    function UploadFile(file) {

    // following line is not necessary: prevents running on SitePoint servers
    if (location.host.indexOf("sitepointstatic") >= 0) return

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload && file.type == "image/jpeg" && file.size <= $id("MAX_FILE_SIZE").value) {

        // create progress bar
        var o = $id("progress");
        var progress = o.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
        progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode("upload " + file.name));


        // progress bar
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
            progress.style.backgroundPosition = pc + "% 0";
        }, false);

        // file received/failed
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
            }
        };

        // start upload
        xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
        xhr.send(file);//This is line 116

    }

}
```

Line 41 is the call UploadFile(f);

Comment: check you api method.

Comment: The 405 error has nothing to do with CORS. The server just forbids POST requests to it. You've told us nothing about how the server is configured so we can't know why it is rejecting POST requests.

Comment: Which api method?

Comment: Quentin, those are all the codes what I'm using as client and server.  How I see the configuration server?

Answer (score 1):

Please see `php.ini` configuration (on the server), as described in the documentation. There are several options for uploading fles. You can find it on php.net e.g.